# Symfony3: Default parameter gets first entry even when defaulted to null

Tags: symfony

I am trying to create an action in my controller that handles a null value for `category` if it's not passed in.

I've tried annotating 2 routes (one without `/{category}`) but in every case, when I do not supply a category in the URL, Symfony retrieves the 1st category it can find.

```
@Route("/accounts/{id}/categories/{category}", defaults={"category" = null})
```

The action definition looks like this:

```
public function categoryAction(Request $request, Account $account, Category $category)
```

I have also tried `$category = null` in the action, but that does not make a difference.

How can I make this action have a `$category` with a value of `null` if the category is not defined in the url?

Update:

To be clear, here is the full annotation and function definition with comments on my xdebug results:

```
/**
 * @Route("/accounts/{id}/categories")
 * @Route("/accounts/{id}/categories/{category}, defaults={"category" = null}")
 */
public function categoryAction(Request $request, Account $account, Category $category = null)
    {
        // When I set a breakpoint here, $category is populated with
        // the first category result in the database.
        // This is when visiting: http://localhost:8000/accounts/1/categories
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define multiple routes for same actions, maybe try something like :

```
/**
 * @Route("/accounts/{id}/categories")
 * @Route("/accounts/{id}/categories/{category}")
 * @Template()
 */
public function categoryAction(Request $request, Account $account, Category $category)
{
```

And if you try to access `/accounts/{id}/categories`, `$category` will be `null`

Comment: Maybe my problem is somewhere else then. This is what I meant about trying to annotate 2 routes, one without /category. Even when that is the only route annotated, and I use php to default `$category = null`, `$category` is still populated with a value.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is the change you should make:

```
/**
 * @Route("/accounts/{id}/categories", defaults={"category" = null}")
 * @Route("/accounts/{id}/categories/{category})
 */
public function categoryAction(Request $request, Account $account, Category $category)
{
    ...
```

Can you try it and let us know? I haven't tested it, but I think it's right.

Comment: I just tried this, same result. `$category` is populated with the first category value in the db when visiting `http://localhost:8000/accounts/1/categories`. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Hi Coder1. Can you edit your post and tell us what the console command `php bin/console debug:router` shows? Thanks!